# How to Create a URL in asp.net core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

from a controller in asp.net core 3.1 application, I need to create a link that will lead to something like this

> https://myhost/mycontroller/myaction/itemId.

This link is meant to be contained in an email message to be automatically sent out by the application when necessary. The recipient of the email is meant to click on the link and land on the url in my application. If the application is running on localhost, I expect the link to be something like https://locahost:1234//mycontroller/myaction/itemId and when it is on a remote web server, I expect the link to be https:://theapplications/mycontroller/myaction/itemId

I did this

```
Url.Action("myaction",new { sr.Id })
```

and realized that when I use this in an email, from the email, it does not point to https://myhost/mycontroller/myaction/itemId

It rather points to "http://theemailhostaddress/myaction/itemid"

Please how can I achieve this from my controller

Thank you.

Comment: `Url.Action` generates a *relative* URL. If you want to include the host, prepend the `Request.Host` value to it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Example please. Something like this? Request.Host + Url.Action("details",new { sr.Id})

Comment: Request.Host + Url.Action("details",new { sr.Id}) actually worked for me but I am just wondering whether there is a better way to do it considering best practices

Comment: Yes, something like that. IIRC, there's no way to generate an absolute URL with any of the helpers. You *could* use the `ActionLink` extension with something like `Url.ActionLink("action", "controller", "id", Request.Scheme, Request.Host.ToString())` (or similar) but I'm not sure if that's any better

Comment: If you can add this as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
string link = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Url.Action("myaction", "mycontroller", new { itemId = sr.Id});
```